# implementation of Zmq with google protocol buffer in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, pyzmq

I am trying to implement below scenario in python. need help to get any good example of similar implementation.

```
---------    
Module 1
---------    
Module 2
---------        
Module 3
---------
```

I want to develop a Python framework with Google Protocol Buffer such that messages can be passed through module1 to module2 to module3 and vice versa.

I have created protocol message file. I created a thread in module2, in which I also created zmq sockets.

Now I want to add something similar to zloop in python, where I can listen for message coming from either module 1 or 3 and then pass it.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing its own eventloop like czmq, pyzmq integrates the [tornado ioloop](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html) in `zmq.eventloop.ioloop`.

A simple example relaying and logging any messages on `incoming`, and sending the same message unmodified on `outgoing`:

```
import zmq
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop, zmqstream
loop = ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

ctx = zmq.Context()

incoming = ctx.socket(zmq.PULL)
incoming.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555')
outgoing = ctx.socket(zmq.PUSH)
outgoing.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5556')

sincoming = zmqstream.ZMQStream(incoming, loop)
soutgoing = zmqstream.ZMQStream(outgoing, loop)

def relay(msg):
    print("relaying %s" % "|".join('%r' % part for part in msg))
    soutgoing.send_multipart(msg)

sincoming.on_recv(relay)

loop.start()
```

The key to the whole thing is the `stream.on_recv` method, which lets you register a callback to run whenever a message arrives on the socket.

[the pyzmq eventloop docs](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/eventloop.html#on-recv)